# blower moter on my hvac dosent work after changing both capacitors

Tags: hvac

my blower motor on my havoc stopped working so I changed both of the capacitors. when I set the inside thermostat to just fan the blower motor works but very slowly and does not work at all when I set the inside thermostat to cool

Comment: If you'll [edit] your question to include the brand/model of the equipment involved, including a picture of the name plate of the _motor_ itself, there's a good chance that someone can help you with trouble shooting. Otherwise, just load a new part into the parts canon and fire away...

Answer (score 5):

Despite a world full of people who are sure the only possible problem with a motor must be a capacitor, there are other things that can fail. Control systems, starter switches, insulation failure, bad bearings, *etc...*

How did you diagnose it as being a failed capacitor, if at all? Throwing a capacitor at it only works if it just happens to be a capacitor failure.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you reversed which capacitor goes where.

They capacitance are not the same.

As you pointed out you have two capacitors.

One is for the motor start (the larger capacitance one) the other is for motor run.